# What causes the jittering in this cloth simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

My cloth keeps jittering after its been sewn together, what causes this? [Here's](https://media.giphy.com/media/WOAMx1wPZPipK77BQh/giphy.gif) an example of what im talking about.

Link to the file:

https://pasteall.org/media/a/e/aebde9cef9f2640c69a7aa036f0e8ff4.blend

Cloth Settings
[image]

[image]

Collision Settings
[image]

Comment: multiple possibilites, can you expand this question and give us screenshots of your settings or whole file? Maybe it is due to collision margin, maybe too much force for sewing... hard to guess

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? It would allow us to test (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

Turn up the quality steps to 20, then it looks much more stable:

[image]